# Binary AND operator

Tags: python, binary

```
A = 0b111 (7)

B = 0b1010 (10)

A & B = 0b10 (2)
```

The first numbers are both 1's, so you get a 1.
Then you have 1 and 0 so you get a 0 and then you get 1 and 1 again.

But the answer is apparently 0b10 so it's skipped for some reason. (as well as the last 0 in B)

Could someone explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 12):

You need to start with the *least* significant bits (the ones written on the right), not the most significant bits. The "first" digit of `A` is 0, not 1; when you seem have too few bits, you need to supply zeros.

```
    A = 0b0111
    B = 0b1010
A & B = 0b0010
```

Just like in regular decimal, 10 + 7 = 17, not 80.

Comment: Correct, and more generally, all leading digits that are unspecified are zero. This is the same as they are represented in decimal, e.g. 195 is the same as 00000000195 (or however many leading zeros you want).